# Problems with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm writing a vector array to an ofstream file, however certain values aren't getting written, I.E.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    char * hold = new char [100];
    vector<double> fx(2049);
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream myFile;
    inputFile.open("data.txt");
    myFile.open("test.txt");
    for (int c=0; c<2049; c++){
         inputFile.getline(hold, 100);
         fx[c] = atof(hold);
    }
    for (int c=0; c<2049; c++){
         myFile << fx[c] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Within fx, the second half is all equal to 0. (fx[1024] through fx[2048]==0). Within test.txt however, none of these 0 values are present, on the carriage return is applied. Any thoughts? 
Thanks! (New to the formatting of these questions... any tips to make this more understandable would be appreciated.)

Note: I realize this program is rather redundant. The actual program has a great deal more functionality to it, this is just an area that is working incorrectly.

Comment: Can we see `input()`?

Comment: I can't spot any problems within the code you posted. Perhaps more code would help? :o

Comment: I added in what I'm using as an input for fx[c].

Comment: Could you pastebin `data.txt` and your resultant `test.txt`? http://pastie.org

Comment: http://pastie.org/7118709 is the test file, and http://pastie.org/7118727 is the data file. They appear the same, excluding the lack of 0's.

Comment: Odd that the output file ends after 8192 characters = 8*1024, buffer problem. Is it reading in all the numbers? If it is then could be it is writing the first full buffer but not the second. Maybe you just needs to force the buffer to write output. Try myFile.flush();

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#define MAX_FILE_LINES 2048


using namespace std;

//genarate random double number
double fRand()
{
    double fMin = 100, fMax = 200;
    double f = (double)rand();    
    return fMin + (f / (fMax - fMin));  
}

//init file (if you need to create sample file with list of double numbers, you can use this function)
void fileInit(){    
    ofstream sourceFile;    
    sourceFile.open("D:\\source.txt");
    if (sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_FILE_LINES; i++){
            sourceFile << fRand() << endl;
        }
    }
}


int main (){
    string buffer;
    vector<double> fx(MAX_FILE_LINES);  
    ifstream sourceFile;
    ofstream destinationFile;
    sourceFile.open("D:\\source.txt");
    destinationFile.open("D:\\destination.txt");

    //reading file lines to vector
    int lineCount =0;
    if (sourceFile.is_open())
      {
        while ( sourceFile.good() )
        {
          getline (sourceFile,buffer);
          fx[lineCount] = atof(buffer.c_str());
          lineCount++;
          if (lineCount == (MAX_FILE_LINES-1)){
              break;
          }
        }
        sourceFile.close();
      }

    //write lines to new file
    if (destinationFile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i=0; i<MAX_FILE_LINES; i++){
         destinationFile << fx[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works much better! Thank you! I think there was some flaw within the buffer of the output. I'm not sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why screw with handroll buffers for one-offs?  You can't save a millionth of what it costs to think about cycles here, there's not enough waste to recoup.

Think about eliminating needless statements and unchecked failures first.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<float> data;
    {
        ifstream ids("source.txt",ios_base::in);
        int linenr = 0;
        for ( string line ; getline(ids,line) ; ) {
            ++linenr;
            decltype(data)::value_type x;
            istringstream s(line);
            if ( s >> x ) 
                data.push_back(x);
            else
                cerr << "crap line "<<linenr<<" ignored: " << line << '\n';
        }
    }
    ofstream ods("object.txt");
    for ( auto x : data )
        ods << x << '\n';
}
```